# Can't dock in Artemis Bridge Simulator

Tags: artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator

I sponsored my first Artemis session at home last weekend.  Everyone on the bridge other than me was a newbie.  We ran into a recurring problem of not being able to dock.

When I've seen this problem before, I attributed it to being at the wrong vertical height.  So I just moved up/down until I found the sweet spot.

During our recent session, this did not appear to be the case.  No matter our vertical level, the DS wouldn't tractor us properly.

I made sure out helm programmed 0 velocity, was within a range of 500 m (sometimes we were as close as 20 m), and we tried many elevations.  The tractor started but stopped almost immediately.  The only way were able to restore our energy levels was to spam the dock request hundreds of times.

So, what could be causing our docking problems?  How can we avoid them in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two possible answers on the Artemis forums:

**Joystick issues:**
We were using a joystick and some joysticks don't actually get down to zero.  A small non-zero velocity will cause the ship to undock.  It can be fixed by following the directions on the [Artemis Forums](http://artemis.forumchitchat.com/post/docking-issue-with-saitek-throttle-6764144?highlight=joystick+dock&pid=1285257540#post1285257540).

**Stations hate you:**
Our first time tactical officer fired on the first ship we came across.  I don't recall whether he destroyed the ship or not.  Regardless, harming or killing friendlies pisses of the local stations.

**Lesson: don't shoot friendlies**.